# OpenSSL DES_PCBC

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, cryptography, des

I have to use Crypto (OpenSSL) in a C# project. I need to encrypt a message using DES_pcbc_encrypt(). I have tried looking at a C# wrapper on [here](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) for OpenSSL libraries but it seems that DES_PCBC is not provided here. Please I have spend several hours trying to find this type on encryption to be used on C# but I have had no success. Please any direction/help would be appreciate it. I have no access to the software that is decrypting the message I just know is using DES_pcbc.

Comment: It's just CBC with an extra XOR of the plaintext block. Bouncy Castle doesn't have it, but it would be pretty easy to implement it starting with `CbcBlockCipher.cs`. Note that asking for examples is explicitly off topic here, I would advise to rewrite the question a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have never used CBC or any type of cryptography before that is why I was asking for an example or any kind of direction in this manner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've implemented it but I could only find some test vectors [here](https://code.google.com/p/phlexik/source/browse/trunk/tango/util/cipher/modes/PCBC.d?r=69) - and they turned out to be incorrect. I.e. I implemented it first go. Took me many times longer to find test vectors [here](http://www.directorandgeneral.com/aes/questions.php) and they are in *image* format. Sheesh. I'll try and post the result in Java tomorrow, should be a doodle to implement the changes in C#. If you already have an implementation you can send it or some test vectors to me.